# Mocha not respecting timeout or done callback when running CasperJS tests

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, casperjs

So here is the issue that I'm trying to solve with casperjs and mocha. I'm trying to test an element's text value on a page to see if its updating over a period of... 5-10 seconds. The idea being I grab the value, push it in to an array, wait 500ms and repeat until the array has 20 items. Thats about 10 seconds. Then run underscore/lodash's `_.uniq` function on the array and test that the array length is `> 1`.

The problem I'm running in to is that mocha is not waiting for this to complete because stating the test is a success/failure. I thought I could increase mocha's timeout but this has not made any difference. Please see the code below. I've commented it for readability.

```
it('has elements whose values update', function () {
  // 20 seconds, which should be plenty of time
  this.timeout(20000);

  casper.then(function() {
        // The test array
    var values = [],
        // So we can stop the intervals
        intervalId;

    function getValue () {
      // Grab element's text value
      var value = casper.evaluate(function () { return $('#element').text(); });

      // Push in to our test array
      values.push(value);

      // 20 * 500ms == 10 seconds or 10000ms
      // When set to 500ms, this block never runs. The test passes before it has a chance to
      if (values.length === 20) {

        // Stop it from checking the value any further
        clearInterval(intervalId);

        // Test to see we've had more than one unique value in the 10 seconds
        expect(_.uniq(values).length).to.be.gt(1);
      } 
    } 

    // Wait for the value on the page to populate
    // It defaults to '-' when the page loads
    casper.waitFor(function () {
      return this.evaluate(function () {
        return $('#element').text() !== '-';
      });

    // Start the check with a delay of 500ms between each check
    }, function then() {
      intervalId = setInterval(getValue, 500);
    });
  });
});
```

With the interval value set at 500ms I get 2-3 element values in `values` before mocha moves on to the next test. Even odder is when I `console.log(values)` they are printing on screen AFTER mocha as determined the test passed. The reason is that `values.length` never gets to 10 so the `expect` call is never called. The test is assumed to be passing. Here is the test output at 500ms interval:

```
Dashboard
✓ has elements whose values update (202ms)
Values: ["20,832,022"]
Values: ["20,832,022","20,832,372"]
Values: ["20,832,022","20,832,372","20,832,722"]

✓ has the page title of leads (41ms)

2 passing (11s)
```

It passes even though there isn't 20 items. It never checks it due to a timeout somewhere. Here is the output with 50ms interval:

```
Dashboard

✓ has elements whose values update (341ms)
Values: ["20,400,667"]
Values: ["20,400,667","20,400,718"]
Values: ["20,400,667","20,400,718","20,400,718"]
Values: ["20,400,667","20,400,718","20,400,718","20,400,769"]
Values: ["20,400,667","20,400,718","20,400,718","20,400,769","20,400,769"]
Values: ["20,400,667","20,400,718","20,400,718","20,400,769","20,400,769","20,400,820"]
Values: ["20,400,667","20,400,718","20,400,718","20,400,769","20,400,769","20,400,820","20,400,820"]
Values: ["20,400,667","20,400,718","20,400,718","20,400,769","20,400,769","20,400,820","20,400,820","20,400,871"]
Values: ["20,400,667","20,400,718","20,400,718","20,400,769","20,400,769","20,400,820","20,400,820","20,400,871","20,400,871"]
Values: ["20,400,667","20,400,718","20,400,718","20,400,769","20,400,769","20,400,820","20,400,820","20,400,871","20,400,871","20,400,922"]
Final Values: ["20,400,667","20,400,718","20,400,718","20,400,769","20,400,769","20,400,820","20,400,820","20,400,871","20,400,871","20,400,922"]

✓ has the page title of leads (41ms)

2 passing (8s)
```

I get more with the 50ms but that's only a half second of testing. Some of the other values on the page take longer to update to this is not viable.

I've tried passing the `done` callback to the `it` statement but mocha ignores it and doesn't wait for it to be called.

Is this a limitation of the tools or am I using them wrong?

I have tried using the done callback using the method below.

```
it('has elements whose values update', function (done) {
```

and

```
expect(_.uniq(values).length).to.be.gt(1);
done();
```

It still ignores that I've marked the test as async. At 500ms it still passes without getting to the if statement or done call. At 50ms it throws this error:

```
done() called multiple times
```

I am using [mocha-casperjs](https://github.com/nathanboktae/mocha-casperjs). Could this be affecting it?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that mocha-casperjs doesn't use the default `done`. It knows that the test step is complete because it uses CasperJS' control flow. In your case, you break out of the control flow by calling `getValue` through a `setInterval`.

It would be better to refactor your code to use recursive calls to `getValue` like this:

```
function getValue () {
  // Grab element's text value
  var value = this.evaluate(function () { return $('#element').text(); });

  // Push in to our test array
  values.push(value);

  // 20 * 500ms == 10 seconds or 10000ms
  // When set to 500ms, this block never runs. The test passes before it has a chance to
  if (values.length === 20) {
    // Test to see we've had more than one unique value in the 10 seconds
    expect(_.uniq(values).length).to.be.gt(1);
  } else {
    this.wait(500, getValue);
  }
} 

// Wait for the value on the page to populate
// It defaults to '-' when the page loads
casper.waitFor(function () {
  return this.evaluate(function () {
    return $('#element').text() !== '-';
  });

// Start the check with a delay of 500ms between each check
}, function then() {
  this.wait(500, getValue);
});
```

This makes `getValue` a casper step.

Another solution without much refactoring is letting a second `waitFor` run along side of the broken control flow. This needs a semi-global variable `someGlobalVariable`. Maybe the `intervalId` can be used for this, but it's probably better to use `someGlobalVariable = false;` at the top.

```
intervalId = setInterval(getValue, 500);
this.waitFor(function check(){
    return someGlobalVariable;
}, function then(){
   // do something else
}, null, 20000);
```

and let it stop with

```
expect(_.uniq(values).length).to.be.gt(1);
someGlobalVariable = true;
```